# Binding an element to a BehaviorSubject in an Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a small shared Angular service which looks as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
    private _isOpen: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    constructor() {
        this._isOpen.subscribe(val => {
            console.log(`isOpen: ${val}`);
        });
    }

    public get isOpen() {
        return this._isOpen.asObservable();
    }

    toggle() {
        this._isOpen.next(!this._isOpen.getValue());
    }
}
```

And I would like to bind the `.isOpen` property to an element in a view. I am currently using the following snippet to attempt binding in the view:

```
<p>Sidebar State: {{sidebarService?.isOpen | async}}</p>
```

The property is binding initially, however not responding to successive changes. What I want is for **Sidebar State:** to update when the sidebar toggle() method is called inside SidebarService.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you could get a new `Observable` every time the getter is called. Have you tried changing your code to `getIsOpen(): Observable<boolean>` and calling it once at the initialization of your component?

Comment: Tried that, moving the .asObservable call to my constructor. Picking up now that my SidebarService is being duplicated. I can see the constructor is firing twice. The service is supposed to be shared.

Comment: How many times do you import your service ? And where ? You're supposed to import it only once, not in a shared module for example

Comment: Hard to guess what's the cause for that...are you using it somewhere else?

Comment: Also, this line is weird : `this._isOpen.next(!this._isOpen.getValue());`

Comment: Found the issue, I had two instances of [providers] registered in in my components. Moved the provider annotation to my app,module.ts and all works fine now.

Comment: @Maxime All I'm doing is negating the boolean value of whatever getValue() currently is for isOpen.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was caused by having multiple instances of the SidebarService running.

I fixed the issue by moving the declarations for providers in the @Component decorators from two components that shared the SidebarService to *app.module.ts* like so:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // ...
        SidebarComponent,
        // ...
    ],
    imports: [ /* ... */ ])
    ],
    // Line below was duplicated in two components,
    // causing multiple instances...
    providers: [SidebarService], // <--
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This means that my binding was observing changes on a whole different instance of an Observable all together.

I also found that the .asObservable() call is entirely unnecessary, so the resulting SidebarService now looks as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
    private _isOpen: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this._isOpen = new BehaviorSubject(true);
    }

    public get isOpen() {
        return this._isOpen;
    }

    toggle() {
        this._isOpen.next(!this._isOpen.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware, that `BehaviorSubject.getValue()` is now replaced with `BehaviorSubject.value`